# What are the arguments for convert_input_data in PyTorch-BigGraph

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to use [PyTorch-BigGraph](https://github.com/facebookresearch/PyTorch-BigGraph) following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-pytorch-biggraph-with-examples-b50ddad922b8). However I get an error when executing this command:

```
from torchbiggraph.converters.import_from_tsv import convert_input_data

convert_input_data(
    CONFIG_PATH,
    edge_paths,
    lhs_col=0,
    rhs_col=1,
    rel_col=None,
)


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-415dd5cca44f> in <module>
      3 from torchbiggraph.converters.import_from_tsv import convert_input_data
      4 
----> 5 convert_input_data(
      6     CONFIG_PATH,
      7     edge_paths,

TypeError: convert_input_data() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'entity_path', 'edge_paths_out', 'edge_paths_in', and 'edgelist_reader'
```

However I don't know what these 4 arguments are and can't find the answer in the available documentation.

Comment: Does line 342 onwards of [this](https://github.com/facebookresearch/PyTorch-BigGraph/blob/main/torchbiggraph/converters/importers.py) help?

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish Not really.

Comment: Even I couldn't find any source or documentation on this. I would suggest you wait for a day and start a bounty if you don't get any answer.